# Problem in upload bootloader into esp32

Tags: bootloader, compilation-errors

I have problem with my esp32 Device and asked one question as you can see below:

[How to understand the ESP32 is working (Error: Arduino unknown board ...)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/85880/how-to-understand-the-esp32-is-working-error-arduino-unknown-board)

As it is not fixed, so I am thinking to upload the bootloader codes on the ESp32.
SO I have tried the ArduinoISP example codes and tried to  use the bootloader icon on Arduino, but it doesn't work,
and I get below error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.burnBootloader(SerialUploader.java:329)
    at processing.app.Editor.lambda$handleBurnBootloader$61(Editor.java:2379)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Error while burning bootloader.
```

Also, the whole process is show below:

[image]

So I have asked here for some comments or answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. esp32 has a fixed bootloader in read only memory. it is not replaceable
2. ArduinoISP sketch is a programmer only for classic ATmega MCU boards
3. in valid case you would have to select the programmer in Tools menu before using Burn Bootloader. (There are no options in your Programmer menu, because no programmers are defined for esp32 boards package)